# Understanding why my system froze

Tags: freeze, syslog

earlier this evening my home server running ubuntu just stopped responding. I first noticed the connection to the outside world had gone. Then noticed server stopped responding to ssh login-requests. I went to it and power it off and back on. Everything came back and appears normal again.

I just can't figure out why it hung like it did out of nowhere.

This is from the moment just before i rebooted it. Earlier in syslog is nothing apart from openvpn entries that I know are normal. Then this:

```
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd-modules-load[387]: Inserted module 'msr'
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Set the console keyboard layout.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service: Succeeded.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module chromeos_pstore.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Succeeded.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: modprobe@efi_pstore.service: Succeeded.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module efi_pstore.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: modprobe@pstore_blk.service: Succeeded.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module pstore_blk.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: modprobe@pstore_zone.service: Succeeded.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module pstore_zone.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: modprobe@ramoops.service: Succeeded.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module ramoops.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Modules.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Uncomplicated firewall.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Activating swap /swapfile...
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd-random-seed[399]: Kernel entropy pool is not initialized yet, waiting until it is.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd-sysctl[400]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/all/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd-sysctl[400]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/default/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Activated swap /swapfile.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Apply Kernel Variables.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished udev Coldplug all Devices.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Starting udev Wait for Complete Device Initialization...
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Create System Users.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Show Plymouth Boot Screen being skipped.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch being skipped.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Random Seed.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd-udevd[425]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd-udevd[421]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd-udevd[412]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd-udevd[425]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd-udevd[428]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd-udevd[421]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd-udevd[412]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd-udevd[428]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Found device /dev/ttyS0.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd-udevd[408]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER udevadm[404]: systemd-udev-settle.service is deprecated.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Mounting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: Mounted Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System.
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Automount point already active?
Nov 26 21:29:42 SERVER systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 472 (snap)
```

Then I hard rebooted it. Does this give anyone any idea as to what happened?

Comment: Not seeing much useful troubleshooting information in that log. Looks like one second of a fairly normal boot instead of ongoing operation terminating in a restart. A "freeze" or "hang" can have many possible causes. Most commonly these days it is a kernel crash which can be caused by anything from a bug to a malicious actor to a stray cosmic ray to a hardware fault. Or a dozen other possibilities. If it occurs frequently, then begin to look for patterns that can rule in/out some of those possibilities.